# How to disable next button in flow builder

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have built a form using the flow builder and I would like the "Next" button to be disabled until all required conditions are met.

Is this functionality possible to implement using the flow builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but not without creating an Aura-Component.

At first you have to create the component and make sure it implements the `lightning:availableForFlowScreens`-Interface (so you can use it inside the flow). A good place to start would be: [Customize the Flow Footer with an Aura Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_replace_footer.htm)

Than by defining some parameters in the components design file you can pass values from your flow to the component. Depending on this values you could hide/display the buttons.

Inside your flow-screen you can disable the default-footer, and replace it with your new custom component.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if you're not using sub-flows, then just unchecked Next/Finish.
[image]

If you are using a subflow, the aforementioned won't prevent the navigation, you would of to use a boolean output variable then outside of the subflow create a decision element to prevent next navigation.

Comment: I just want it to be disabled when all required conditions are not met. If all required conditions are met I want the next button to be enabled. That was my question.